# Why is my second button behaving different when using auto layout constraints?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I can not figure out why my button is behaving different when using auto layout constraints programmatically.

When setting the view that holds my **cancelBtn** every thing is working fine:

```
 let cancelBtnView = TriangularView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150))

 let cancelBtn = UIButton()
 cancelBtnView.addSubview(cancelBtn)
 cancelBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 35, style: .regular)
 cancelBtn.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .times), for: .normal)
 cancelBtn.frame = CGRect(x: cancelBtnView.bounds.width / 16, y: cancelBtnView.bounds.height / 2 ,width: 55, height: 55)
```

I get the following layout:

[image]

When setting up the view for my **doneBtn** I get a different output:

```
let doneBtnView = TriangularView()

 doneBtnView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 doneBtnView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
 doneBtnView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
 doneBtnView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionButtonView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
 doneBtnView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actionButtonView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

 let doneBtn = UIButton()
 doneBtnView.addSubview(doneBtn)
 doneBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 35, style: .regular)
 doneBtn.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .check), for: .normal)

  doneBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  doneBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
  doneBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
  doneBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: doneBtnView.leadingAnchor, constant:    doneBtnView.bounds.width / 16).isActive = true
 doneBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: doneBtnView.bottomAnchor, constant: doneBtnView.bounds.height / 2).isActive = true
```

Setting the constraints for my **doneBtn** programmatically I get the following:

[image]

The constraints for the **doneBtnView** are set programmatically because I want to pin it to the bottom right of its superview.

Comment: Your problem is that you are looking at the bounds of the other view when setting your constraint for your doneBtn, but those bounds will not have been set yet because layout has not happened.  In general, it is a bad idea to combine frame/bounds and constraints. Where do you want the checkMark to be?

Comment: The check mark should be at the same position as the other icon. Or better said: in the middle of the triangle. Should be: **CGRect(x: doneBtnView.bounds.width / 16, y: doneBtnView.bounds.height / 2 ,width: 55, height: 55)** but this places the button near the top of its superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looking at the bounds of the other view when setting your constraint for your `doneBtn`, but those bounds will not have been set yet because layout has not happened. In general, it is a bad idea to combine frame/bounds and constraints.

This can be done, but not with anchors.  Try the following `NSLayoutConstraint`s:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: doneBtn, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: doneBtnView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1/16, constant: 0).isActive = true
    
NSLayoutConstraint(item: doneBtn, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: doneBtnView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1/2, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

and then set the `width` and `height` using anchors:

```
doneBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
doneBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
```

**Note:** Because we're using the `.trailing` and `.bottom` constraints to represent `width` and `height`, it might be necessary to put `doneBtnView` into a container view of the same size because the values will be in the coordinate system of the parent view.  By making the parent view the exact same size, width will be equal to the trailing constraint, and height will be equal to the bottom constraint.

Comment: When looking at the apple docs for **constraint(equalToConstant c: CGFloat)**  in Xcode itself, it says in the discussion part where they compare **Creating a constraint using NSLayoutConstraint.** and **.. using constraintEqualToConstant:** that they behave identical. So I thought there is no difference between using these two methods.

Comment: Your code works perfect btw, but the docs confused me.

Comment: I'm creating constraints that are using multipliers on the trailing and bottom values.  Anchors will not allow you to create these constraints.

Comment: If you set a constant constraint, the value will be fixed.  If you set it relative to another feature of another view, the constraint will be recomputed when the other view changes.  We need it to change, because we can't compute the real value of the position of the checkMark until the doneBtnView has been laid out.